# How can I track the flow of a change caused by a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, audit

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Name] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] CHARACTER VARYING(MAX) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);
```

I control creation of new records with the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Test_Create]
    @SessionId BINARY(32),
    @Name CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    @Description CHARACTER VARYING(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO [Test] ([Name], [Description])
            VALUES (@Name, @Description);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            THROW;
        END CATCH
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

I have a trigger that simply logs the before and after values for this table, for all changes. When my stored procedure is called, this trigger is fired and logs to another table. However, my trigger obviously cannot have the `@SessionId` variable to log which website user session caused the stored procedure to be invoked by the SQL client running on a web server. I do not want to use `SET CONTEXT_INFO` because it is unstable with connection pooling and parallel execution plans.

That said, I thought I could correlate the `@SessionId` passed in to the stored procedure with the `@@SPID` value, but again this is a little tricky with connection pooling. It won't work, as far as I can tell.

How can I track which user on my website, assuming I have a unique session number for them passed into my stored procedure, caused specific changes to any of my tables?

If they invoke a stored procedure, I need to know the stored procedure invoked and how it altered the tables (before and after values).

Is there perhaps an alternative to retrieve the following information **and** link them together to form an audit trail?

- The website user/session that caused a stored procedure to be invoked
- The stored procedure that was invoked and its parameters
- The resultant data queries
- The effects of the queries (before and after data)

Comment: You can't just add the logging to `Test_Create` itself?

Comment: @David If I do that, then I need to write log entries for every single insert, update, or delete and then also figure out what the old values were. This would add a lot of extra code that could be solved by a trigger. I think it would be better just to figure out how to correlate `@SessionId` from the stored procedure context with `@@SPID` from the trigger context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you modify your table structure so that the `@SessionId` value is stored in the table for creation and modification.

I have an ASP.Net app that also must log all changes for auditing purposes, and the tables that require auditing all have

```
CreatedDateTime DateTime NOT NULL
CreatedBy nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
ModifiedDateTime DateTime NULL
ModifiedBy nvarchar(50) NULL
```

columns

Users log in with Windows Authentication, and we pass the user's `domain\username` to all the stored procs so that it can be stored in the `CreatedBy` or `ModifiedBy` col. The `CreatedDateTime`/`ModifiedDateTime` values are set by the stored procs.

Our change log auditing is done by a CLR trigger which just extracts the `ModifiedBy` value on the new record and this is logged as the person making the change.

Using your @SessionId value would work just as well I would think.

Comment: What happens when UserA modifies a record and then UserB modifies the record? Your design doesn't support audit trails and only supports the "most recent" approach.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. While the actual table only shows the last person who changed the record (which is useful for display purposes) The auditing trigger logs to a separate Audit database/table every single field that changes by recording the user/change date/table name/field name/old value /new value. So if a user changes 20 fields in a single update, then the log table will have 20 rows showing what happened.

Comment: Further to my last comment, this has served us well for the past 7 years and has allowed us to revert changes when necessary, and also carry out detective work to resolve bugs or to validate/repudiate a user's claim that "I didn't do that!". The only downside is that our Audit table now dwarfs the real database.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is "why"?

A few options based on your potential answer:

If you are just curious and want to do some investigation into a problem you can use SQL Server Profiler or Database Engine Trace Capture and Trace Replay with the correct logging events. This will tell you exactly which procedures have been called, by why user and with the correct parameters.

If you want to use this information immediately for management reporting, I suggest you pass it into your stored procedures and store it in a table so you can interrogate it as needed.

If you want to use this information at some point in the future, you could turn logging on around your data access layer to store the information before and after your query either in a log file or again in the database if you really want to.

Comment: The purpose is for security auditing and recovery. We need to know which user on our website changed some data. We are trying to build a recovery feature for when a malicious user deletes a lot of content and we need to suspend the user and then rollback only what they have done and catch any legitimate edits/additions in the crossfire. The reason we want to control as much of it in the database as possible is because we have decentralized parts of this system; many trusted clients connect to the SQL Server instance and make changes on behalf of their user base.

Comment: In which case I would go with the middle option above. Create  audit tables for the tables that you can use to roll back changes. There are a number of ways to do this. One could be to mirror the table structure with an audit table but this is quite fragile. You could create a more generic structure and update it as you go via triggers e.g. Property (ID, Name, Description), PropertyChanges (ID, PropertyIdChanged, UserId, Date Changed, ValueBefore, ValueAfter). This is good for auditing but some careful thought is required to use it to revert data. Probably other solutions possible!

Comment: So, I tried the trigger method and adding the property changes and all that. I even had it rolling back. The difficulty I found with triggers is that I cannot communicate the `@SessionId` to the trigger, except with `SET CONTEXT_INFO` as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Rather than using triggers, do the insert in the stored procedure and then you can store the sessionid in your audit table without dirtying your main data table.